# videojs : Bug with fullscreen mode and fixed DIV on IE 10 #videojs

Tags: video

I'm using VideoJS and everything works fine on firefox chrome and safari. But on Internet Explorer 10 the fullscreen video appear under my nav-bar (I have some fixed DIV with z-index). http://nielk.github.io/nantes-nord/

I unsuccessful tried to add a greater z-index on videojs css class but there is no result !

Does anyone have a solution ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a workaround, I add a listenner on videojs player, when the fullscreen event is fired I add a class on my fixed DIV (add property 'display : none'). So there is no elements who appear above my fullscreen video.

```
 videojs('video-player-id').ready(function(){
    var myPlayer = this;

    var myFunc = function(){
        var myPlayer = this;

        // Do something when the event is fired
        $('#container-nav').toggleClass('fullscreen-ie');
        $('#scroll-top').toggleClass('fullscreen-ie');
    };

    myPlayer.on("fullscreenchange", myFunc);

});
```

CSS :

```
.fullscreen-ie {
    display: none;
}
```